# aplicar cambios con sed en líneas separadas

Tags: sed

con un dataset como el que muestro a continuación, quiero conseguir hacer varios cambios mediante `sed` pero no quiero hacerlos en una única línea, sino en varias.

Lo que me ocurre es los valores de salida son una tabla con los cambios hechos por `sed` pero en cada línea por separado.

Este es el dataset:

```
name,"gender","age","class","embarked","country","ticketno","fare","sibsp","parch","survived"
Abbing, Mr. Anthony,"male",42,"3rd","S","United States",5547,7.11,"0","0","no"
Abbott, Mr. Eugene Joseph,"male",13,"3rd","S","United States",2673,20.05,"0","2","no"
Abbott, Mr. Rossmore Edward,"male",16,"3rd","S","United States",2673,20.05,"1","1","no"
Abbott, Mrs. Rhoda Mary 'Rosa',"female",39,"3rd","S","England",2673,20.05,"1","1","yes"
Abelseth, Miss. Karen Marie,"female",16,"3rd","S","Norway",348125,7.13,"0","0","yes"
Abelseth, Mr. Olaus JÃ¸rgensen,"male",25,"crew","S","United States",348122,7.13,"0","0","yes"
Abelson, Mr. Samuel,"male",30,"2nd","C","France",3381,24,"1","0","no"
Abelson, Mrs. Hannah,"female",28,"2nd","C","France",3381,24,"1","0","yes"
Abi-Al-MunÃ , Mr. Nasif Qasim,"male",27,"3rd","C","Lebanon",2699,18.1509,"0","0","yes"
Abrahamsson, Mr. Abraham August Johannes,"male",20,"3rd","S","Finland",3101284,7.1806,"0","0","yes"
```

Estas son las instrucciones que quiero hacer:

```
sed -e 's/1st/First/g' -e 's/2nd/Second/g' -e 's/3rd/Third/g' titanic.csv

sed -e's/, Mr.//g' -e 's/, Mrs.//g' titanic.csv

sed -e 's/,"C",/,"Cherbourg",/g' -e 's/,"Q",/,"Queenstown",/g' -e 's/,"S",/,"Southhampton",/g' titanic.csv

sed -e's/"//g' titanic.csv
```

Estoy pensando que una opción podría ser haciendo el guardado en una variable. Tiene sentido?

```
nuevaExtension = $(awk sed -e ......)
```

Comment: utiliza pipes: `sed -e '...' fichero | sed -e '...'`. De este modo, lo que sale de un comando es la entrada del siguiente.